# What does a vertical bar mean in this context?

Tags: notation

I'm doing a few exercises regarding Schnorr's identification scheme.
I have [the exercise](https://books.google.com/books?id=owd76BElvosC&pg=PA456&lpg=PA456&dq=schnorr%20identification%20%22311%22%2031&source=bl&ots=zNHexZBHgX&sig=ACfU3U3z93wmItSVguC_sAX24c_VTXI5_A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSvfmE2NPwAhXaQc0KHaJjDiYQ6AEwEnoECBUQAw#v=onepage&q=schnorr%20identification%20%22311%22%2031&f=false) starting off like this, with the values defined:

> Let $p = 311$ and $r = 31\ |\ (p - 1)$. Let $g = 169$, which has order $r$.

I just really can't figure out what the vertical bar means here?

Sometimes in discrete maths, a vertical bar means absolute value, sometimes two them are cardinalty? Programming would suggest that it means a logical or?

One place I saw something indicating that it might be xor, but I really have no idea.

Comment: Do you have more context? $|$ can also mean divides in that 31 divides 310, but it doesn't make sense to assign that to $r$

Comment: @AmanGrewal This is apparently a widely used problem, see https://books.google.com/books?id=owd76BElvosC&pg=PA456&lpg=PA456&dq=schnorr+identification+%22311%22+31&source=bl&ots=zNHexZBHgX&sig=ACfU3U3z93wmItSVguC_sAX24c_VTXI5_A&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiSvfmE2NPwAhXaQc0KHaJjDiYQ6AEwEnoECBUQAw#v=onepage&q=schnorr%20identification%20%22311%22%2031&f=false for one example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The meaning of that $\ \vert\ $ in this context is *divides* (as in *evenly divides*, or *is a divisor of*), and that's a standard usage of this sign. The quote should be read as:

> let $p=311$ and $r=31$, which divides $(p-1)$. Let $g=169$…

In other words: $r$ is a divisor of $p-1$. Or, exists integer $q$ with $r\times q=p-1$. Or, $((p-1)\bmod r)=0$, also writable as $p-1\bmod r=0$ or $p-1\equiv0\pmod r$ or $p\equiv1\pmod r$. In many common programing languages, `(p-1)%r == 0`. That's because $31$ (evenly) divides $311-1$, since $31\times10=310$.

That was correctly guessed by Aman Grewal in [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/198968), but as noted, proximity with the assignment makes the notation confusing. Elision of the implied *which* is something I would try to avoid.

---

> The end of the sentence says «Let $g=169$, which has order $r$». Does that mean that $g$ is really `169%31`?

No. The term *order* is used in its [meaning in group theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(group_theory)). In this context, it means that when we repeatedly multiply $1$ by $g$, reducing modulo $p$ after each multiplication, we'll first get back to $1$ after performing $r$ multiplications. That's related to $r\,\vert\,(p-1)$, because the order of any element in a finite group is a divisor of the order of the group, that is the number of elements in the group. Here the group is the [multiplicative group modulo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n) $p$, noted $\mathbb Z_p^*$ or $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)^\times$, which has $p-1$ elements since $p$ is prime. The powers of $g$ form a [subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroup) of order $r$, called a [Schnorr group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group).

Comment: Thanks, One more thing that I don't understand. The end of the sentence says `Let G=169, which has order r` does that mean that G is really 169%31?

Comment: thanks a lot again. A quick addition though,. I have just received an answe that the actual value of r is actually 8? How does this make sense?

Comment: @Garsty100: [Asking Wolfram _order of 169 modulo 311_](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=order+of+169+modulo+311) yields 31, thus the quote is correct. I recommend studying some group theory. That serves in many fields (including the non-mathematical sense of that).

Comment: “Let… $r$ be 31, **which divides** $(p-1)$…”